# Magic mouse in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, magic-mouse

I have installed ubuntu on my mac.
I have a magic mouse as well and I am trying to use it.
The bluetooth detects it and it moves and everything
but there is this acceleration problem.

On googling I found this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleMagicMouse
but where is the linux 2.6 directory?
Probably a very dumb question.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? If you are using the latest version (currently 11.04) there should be no need to read past where it says 'Ubuntu 10.04 and earlier'. The instructions mentioning the linux 2.6 directory are for patching the Linux kernel which is an advanced topic and not recommended or a beginner or even intermediate user.

Comment: I tried to use my magic mouse in Ubuntu for a while.. Maybe I'm just an old dog, but I kind of hated it in general (in OSX too).. But my annoyance was purely with the bluetooth component of it. Wireless is so, finicky, I find.. </PeanutGallery>

Answer (score 0):

Kernel headers are the linux source code. If you have it installed it can be found in `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

There was [a guide on the bottom of the page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8777663&postcount=21) you linked. Follow it and you should be fine.